# Is the Access-Control-Allow-Origin CORS header required when doing a preflight request?

Tags: javascript, security, web, cors

We are seeing the well-known CORS error on our site:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://my-site.com/api. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://my-other-site.com' is therefore not allowed access.

The thing is, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` *is* set correctly on the preflight request...

```
OPTIONS https://my-site.com/api HTTP/1.1
Host: my-site.com
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: https://my-other-site.com
Access-Control-Request-Headers: my-custom-header, accept, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: https://my-other-site.com/
...other stuff...


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://my-other-site.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: my-custom-header, accept, content-type
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: my-custom-header
...other stuff...
```

...however, it's *not* set on the subsequent request.

```
POST https://my-site.com/api HTTP/1.1
Host: my-site.com
Accept: */*
My-Custom-Header: abcd123
Origin: https://my-other-site.com
Referer: https://my-other-site.com/
...other stuff...


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
My-Custom-Header: abcd123
...other stuff...
```

I don't understand the problem.  According to *everything* I've read online, if we use a preflight request, we shouldn't need to add CORS headers for the actual request.  However, that's clearly not the case.

All of the examples [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) include an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the actual response, but don't include any of the other *"required"* CORS headers.  When we add that one header to our actual response, the error goes away.

---

So my question is, **is the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header actually required in both requests?**  Where is that stated?  And why is that true?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it appears both responses should include the necessary CORS headers.

In both the [Simple Cross-Origin Request](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/#simple-cross-origin-request-0) and the [Cross-Origin Request with Preflight](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0), the "actual request" follows the same behavior, checking for CORS headers regardless of the preflight (step 1 and step 3, respectively).

> 1. [...] Apply the [make a request steps](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/#make-a-request-steps) and observe the *request rules* below while making the request.
>
>    - ... (snipped: 3xx codes, aborts, and network errors)
>    - **Otherwise**
>
>      Perform a [resource sharing check](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/#resource-sharing-check). [...]

> The **resource sharing check** algorithm for a given resource is as follows:
>
> 1. If the response includes zero or more than one [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/#http-access-control-allow-origin) header values, return fail and terminate this algorithm.
> 2. [...]

The preflight request only prevents the "actual request" from beginning.

Comment: *"the "actual request" follows the same behavior, checking for CORS headers regardless of the preflight"* - Except, that appears to not be true.  The actual request works correctly without the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` or `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` headers.  However *(as I just discovered now)*, it appears the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header is *also* required on both the preflight and the actual request.  WTF!?