# I haven't found anything about how to get the data from AWS S3 into my Angular2 application. I am new to Aws s3

Tags: angular2-services

I am new to AWS S3 ,i dont know how to get data from have link of scraped JSON files on AWS S3 data in angular2 before this i have worked with JSON .
I am creating a web application using angular2 for monthly weather report chart. I have link of scraped  JSON files on AWS S3 for temp data.

Comment: Normally S3 is use to store the media files or static files.

Comment: what kind of data are you looking for?

Comment: Please See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42033953/access-amazon-s3-using-http-in-angular2

Answer (score 0):

Here is your complete solution -
https://grokonez.com/aws/angular-4-amazon-s3-example-get-list-files-from-s3-bucket